# Functions are being are executed twice by node in my slackbot application

Tags: node.js, slack-api

When I start up my application, it sends "App Started" twice, and if I write in Slack (Which is where the app "lives" (sorry for being unable to state this accurately, but you get the point), @saltbot dadjoke everything works but it happens twice. I am using the slackbots library.

This one only gets executed twice (the console log only logs once), but the handleMessage(data) then executes the dadjoke function, which also only has one console.log output. Regardless, the result is that it sends two messages (four total because of 2 per dadjoke()).

```
bot.on('message', (data) => {
    if(data.type !== 'message') {
        return;
    }
        console.log("Message received")
        handleMessage(data);
})
```

*Function that runs twice, but only consoles logs once*

```
const dadJokes = (userId) => {

console.log("Userid: ", userId)

axios({
    "method":"GET",
    "url":"https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/random/jokes",
    "headers":{
    "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
    "x-rapidapi-host":"dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key":"ab6f131638mshd9ccda499375f86p1a3471jsnb7698b37e834",
    "useQueryString":true
    }
    })
    .then((response)=>{  
      bot.postMessage(userId, response.data.setup)
      setTimeout(() => {
          bot.postMessage(userId, response.data.punchline)
      }, 7000)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error)
    })
```

}

Here is the full code: https://github.com/hagenek/saltbot

Answer (score 0):

So.. Not sure if I should delete question or not, but the solution: closed everything and restarted my computer. Loaded up my zsh terminal and ran the app. Now it works.